# ssms upgrade without losing DB credentials

Tags: sql, ssms

I have to upgrade SSMS for an end-user. The problem is that she saves a lot of users and passwords saved with the option of "remember password". I scanned over the internet and couldn't find a solution. Another thing I wish to know is - When the wizard installs the new SSMS - Does it override the old one?

Can 2 versions of SSMS live separately on the same server and can be used by need?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple versions of SSMS installed, though why you would keep an older version around I'm not sure. If you're upgrading the version then that must be to support a new version. The passwords aren't lost though, as I assume the client has ensured to store them in their password management software. If they haven't, then they only have themselves to blame, if I am honest. Being able to get the passwords saved in SSMS out of it would be a security vulnerability.

Comment: SSMS is the client side application, allowing you to develop against a SQL Server installation.  Thus, SSMS shouldn't `live on the server`, it should be on the local machine...

Comment: Thank you all. Sure, the SSMS on the client side. I've installed a newer version and it lives "peacefully" aside the old one. I asked the user to work with RegServers and this way , after export-import between the 2 ssms's ' we'll solve the problem. Thanks again!